# How to troubleshoot EKS pods that fail to start after cluster upgrade?

Tags: amazon-eks

After upgrading an EKS cluster, some of the pods are failing to start, with error messages indicating that they cannot access certain resources or have failed liveness probes. The nodes in the cluster are in a healthy state, and there were no changes made to the pod configurations during the upgrade. The issue only affects a subset of the pods, while others are running normally.

We tried deleting and re-creating the problematic pods, as well as checking the log output of the affected containers, but did not find any clear indicators of the root cause of the problem.

Comment: Could they be referencing a deprecated or removed API? What version did you upgrade to? Are the resources k8s resources or AWS resources?